# django web scraper beautiful soup and urllib

Tags: django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib3

iam using scraper to get some data for my database iam adding products from the other site using this code

```
def scrape():
    path=''
    counter=0

    session= requests.Session()
    session.headers={
        "User-Agent":"my user agent"
    }
    url='some url'
    content=session.get(url,verify=False).content
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(content,'html.parser')
    result=soup.find_all('div',{'class':'column column-block block-list-large single-item'})
    for i in result:
        counter+=1
        name=i.find_all('h1',{'class':'itemTitle'})[0]
        price=i.find('h3',{'class':'itemPrice'})
        image=i.find('img',{'class':'img-size-medium imageUrl'})['data-src']
        path=f'pics/{counter}.jpg'
        img=path
        barcode=f'name{counter}'
        description='this is my product'
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(image,path)
        cat=category.objects.get(id=140)
        br=branch.objects.get(id=8)
        products.objects.create(name=name.text,Barcode=barcode,branch=br,image=img,
        description=description,price=price,category=cat)

scrape()
```

its downloading the image of the product but iam getting an error after this

value = value.resolve_expression(self.query, allow_joins=False, for_save=True)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely `price=price`in create operation. `price` is not a valid value for the field it is an object. Can you change that part with `price=price.text` ?